# why is this turtle collision if statement working? can't track which turtle position is in the statement. tried to track in Pycharm, no luck

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

- ```
    for count in range(15):

   turtle.forward(random.randint(0, 100))

   turtle.right(random.randint(0, 90))

   turtle.forward(random.randint(0, 50))

   turtle.circle(random.randint(0, 50))

   if turtle.pos() == turtle.pos():
     turtle.color("red")
     turtle.speed(0)
     #turtle.penup()
     #turtle.stamp()
     #turtle.hideturtle()
  ```

  > ```
  >     *this code doesnt look right but I am a beginner myself my friend insists it makes the turtle turn red on collision. But how
  > ```

  ```
  does
  > the if statement differentiate between 1 turtle and another? they ARE
  > all red at the end. How is that happening?
  ```

not sure how to use Pycharm to track which turtle is being asked about in the if statement

```
Thanks in Advance I am learning fast.
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: (1) Your code has syntax errors and doesn't work at all.  Please repair these.  (2) The given comparison does *not* "work" as it is a tautology.  (3) Asking us to explain a block of code to you is too broad.  You say "Can't trace", but you fail to show where you had trouble tracing.  (4) If you need to know how your friend's code works, you ask your friend as part of the required research before you post to this site.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a second turtle? if your other turtle is called Turtle2, then it should look like this

```
if turtle.pos() == turtle2.pos():
   turtle.color("red")
   turtle.speed(0)
   #turtle.penup()
   #turtle.stamp()
   #turtle.hideturtle()
```

right now you are looking to see if a turtle's position is the same as a turtle's position (the same values). It will always be true.

Comment: As a rule, `turtle.pos() == turtle2.pos()` won't work.  Turtles crawl a floating point plain and expecting one pair of floating point numbers to exactly match another pair is folly.  Instead we'd do something like `turtle.distance(turtle2) <= 1` using whatever minimal distance makes sense for the given application.

Comment: is it not set by integer coordinates? Cant' remember